# Web service using NodeJS that simulates browser execution from html page with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I'm new to NodeJS and I'm needing to build a web service that will send a response with the result of a javascript script from an HTML page (the page is not local, it's from the web).

For example:

My web page has a javascript script that prints "hello world" (this is an example, the actual page has a lot of functions to calculate the response).

When I use Postman to get this page, the response that I get is the HTML without the javascript execution (without the hello world).

Is there a way to use Node.js to simulate the browser execution? I've done some tests with express, routes, and requests, but they don't execute descript. And I need to execute this script using the URL because it has a lot of os dependencies.

Thanks very much,

Comment: Please add what you created so far.

Comment: You can take a look at pre-rendering projects like prerender.io, or headless browsers like phantom.js

Comment: Thanks Ashish, I will take a look

Answer (score 0):

What I've done so far:

```
var express    = require('express');       
var app        = express();  
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; 



router = express.Router(),
request = require('request');
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

app.use('/test', router);
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     request({
         uri: 'http://qliksense.arysta.com.br/custom/extensions/teste4/teste4.html'
     }).pipe(res);


});

module.exports = router;
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);

});
```

I'll take a look at prerender.io, if someone has a example of how I can fit it to my code, I'll be thankful